# How does hadoop controller calculate percentage of work done ?

Tags: hadoop

I see that whenever I run a Map Reduce task the hadoop job shows me the percentage of Map and Reduce tasks done.

I understand that both mappers and reducers run in a distributed fashion and can report how much they have processed to the controller.

But how does the controller know total data to be processed ? If the controller tries to figure out size of all the input files I would image that will be inefficient. Is it some kind of crude approximation ?

[image: Hadoop Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all the code related to this part in hadoop. but some thought about it, hope it helps

1. map task completion percentage computation:  when a slave machine complete a map task , it will let the master machine know, so it is convenient for master and controller to know the percentage of map task competition, but if the process is blocked or killed the task completed by this process will be reassigned , and the map completed value will decrease in the case.
2. reduce task completion percentage computation: reduce phrase include shuffle task and reduce task, shuffle task start when the map task completion reach 5% , shuffle task mainly copy the data from the map task output directory. so the data copied seems to be domain factor in shuffle part, since the merge sort can be run at the same time. in reduce task, the completion percentage can easily compute by how may "iterators" has been processed.

ps: as vehtfym metioned in the comment: Reduce phase includes copy(finishing at 33%), sort(finishing at 66%) and reduce (finishing at 100%)

Comment: Good points overall. Reduce phase includes `copy`(finishing at 33%), `sort`(finishing at 66%) and `reduce` (finishing at 100%). The percentage of map at which reduce starts is, I think, irrelevant and can be configured differently, through `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps`. You can also manually specify/alter the status of each phase, using the reporter's methods.